# How to move newly added row to top in datagridview winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

In list binded datagidview i added new row dynamicaly by using object.add(item) method,
But by default it added bottom,i want to added it in top,Is it possible??

Comment: `dgvDataSourceList.Insert(indexToInsertInto, ItemToInsert)`

Comment: Or have something like an autoincrmenting int that you sort the grid descending by

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to your collection to a specified index by using [Collection<T>.Insert(index, item)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.insert?view=net-5.0)

in your case that would be:

```
object.Insert(0,item);
```

Comment: In the case of bind source it's ok,But the location of item in gridview still in bottom

Comment: what exactly is your _object_?